# Get the subordinate list of values from a table where the employee and supervisor is mentioned

Tags: oracle, plsql, hierarchical-data

I have a dataset like below

| employee | Supervisor |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| B | C |
| D | E |
| F | B |
| G | F |

In this data set I want to access each employee one by one when I give a supervisor as input.
for an example if I pas B as the input first get A and go B like that till the end and then comeback to F, then go to G.
I want to get them in a order so that I have to apply some data of the top most supervisor to the whole data set.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I understood the question; the first column (`employee`) shows all employees who are subordinate to the supervisor (`c` in this example), while `path` shows ... well, the *path* that leads from chosen supervisor to that employee.

```
SQL> with dataset (employee, supervisor) as
  2    (select 'a', 'b' from dual union all
  3     select 'b', 'c' from dual union all
  4     select 'd', 'e' from dual union all
  5     select 'f', 'b' from dual union all
  6     select 'g', 'f' from dual
  7    )
  8  select
  9    employee,
 10    supervisor,
 11    ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(employee, ' - '), ' - ') as path
 12  from dataset
 13  start with supervisor = 'c'                 --> this is the supervisor you're interested in
 14  connect by supervisor = prior employee;

E S PATH
- - --------------------
b c b
a b b - a
f b b - f
g f b - f - g

SQL>
```

---

If you want to "loop" through employees, then you'll need PL/SQL and ... well, a *loop*. Something like this:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_supervisor varchar2(1) := 'c';
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in
  5      (with dataset (employee, supervisor) as
  6          (select 'a', 'b' from dual union all
  7           select 'b', 'c' from dual union all
  8           select 'd', 'e' from dual union all
  9           select 'f', 'b' from dual union all
 10           select 'g', 'f' from dual
 11          )
 12        select
 13          employee,
 14          supervisor,
 15          ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(employee, ' - '), ' - ') as path
 16        from dataset
 17        start with supervisor = l_supervisor
 18        connect by supervisor = prior employee
 19      )
 20    loop
 21      -- you'd do something with this employee; I'm just displaying it
 22      dbms_output.put_line('Employee = ' || cur_r.employee);
 23    end loop;
 24  end;
 25  /
Employee = b
Employee = a
Employee = f
Employee = g

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you.
@Littlrfoot is there a way to loop through these values in 'path' without getting them as a string ?

Comment: You're welcome. I edited the answer and added the "loop" option you asked for.